# Как правильно скомпилировать релиз?

Tags: android

Что указать в ProGuard чтобы компиляция прошла успешно

```
    Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
Warning:javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.peer.DropTargetContextPeer
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.peer.DragSourceContextPeer
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DirectColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferByte
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferUShort
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSnapshot: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSnapshot: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDropEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.FlavorsComparator: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ - добавить в конфиг такие строчки:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.harmony.awt.**
-dontwarn com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.**
-dontwarn avax.activation.CommandInfo
```

И попробовать, будет ли работать релизная версия так. Это заставить `ProGuard` просто проигнорировать ворнинги. Если работать не будет, то придется разбираться.

Comment: Это работает, но все же помните вы говорили что -dontwarn для другого.

Так я не понимаю все же чем отличается -keep от dontwarn

Comment: @xTIGRx, `keep` заставит не обрабатывать классы,  `dontwarn` проигнорирует предупреждения в результате обработки